# Windows 7 & Dell Latitude E6410 - How do I stop the CD drive opening when I click on the D: drive and there is no disc?

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

When ever I accidentally click on the CD drive in Windows explorer, the drive ejects. 99% of the time, I don't want this to happen. This is slightly annoying. How can I stop this?

Windows 7 on a Dell Latitude E6410.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article: 
http://www.tipandtrick.net/how-to-disable-windows-vista-cd-or-dvd-drive-auto-eject-or-open-feature/

Disabling the autoburn functionality will fix the issue.

Comment: You should copy the important part from the article, not just simply paste a link.